# Why are these buttons not being animated in Firefox or Chrome with CSS3?

Tags: css, animation

Here is the CSS I am using for the animation. Any help getting this working would be very appreciated. The background image is supposed to be getting larger and centering along with the text of the button. However when I hover it sits there with quiet indignation and refuses to move.

```
@keyframes buttonAnim{
    from{
        background-color: rgba(63,62,68,0.75);
        background-size: 40%;
        background-position: left;
        padding-left:40px;
        text-align: left;

    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(63,62,68,0.95);
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        padding-left:0px;
        text-align: center;
   }
}
.button{
    color:White;
    background-image: url(/images/buttonBack.png);
    background-color: rgba(63,62,68,0.75);
    border: white 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-size: 40%;
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 38px;
}
.button:hover{
    animation: buttonAnim 1s;     
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: testing in firefox and chrome

Comment: use -webkit prefix for chrome

Comment: Did you try to use just button without dot prefix (instead of what you put in your code: .button)?

Answer (score 2):

CSS keyframes/animations are still in a vendor-prefixed state, and so require those prefixes to work.

```
/* for Firefox: */
@-moz-keyframes buttonAnim{
    from{
       /* removed for brevity */

    }
    to {
       /* removed for brevity */
   }
}

/* for IE: */
@-ms-keyframes buttonAnim{
    from{
       /* removed for brevity */

    }
    to {
       /* removed for brevity */
   }
}

/* for Opera (under Presto): */
@-o-keyframes buttonAnim{
    from{
       /* removed for brevity */

    }
    to {
       /* removed for brevity */
   }
}

/* for Webkit: */
@-webkit-keyframes buttonAnim{
    from{
       /* removed for brevity */

    }
    to {
       /* removed for brevity */
   }
}

/* for standards compliant browsers when the spec
   is complete/implemented: */
@buttonAnim{
    from{
       /* removed for brevity */

    }
    to {
       /* removed for brevity */
   }
}

/* called with vendor-prefixes too, sadly */
.button:hover{
    -moz-animation: buttonAnim 1s;
    -ms-animation: buttonAnim 1s;
    -o-animation: buttonAnim 1s;
    -webkit-animation: buttonAnim 1s;
    animation: buttonAnim 1s;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LD8wL/).